What would happen to camera if you die on 3rd day but completes view requirement?
In Content Warning, if you (and your whole crew) dies on 1st/2nd day of the game, you can pick up broken camera on the map, so you can upload two videos in a day (if you managed to survive the day and bringing back your camera safely, of course).
But, say, if you managed to complete view requirement on 1st/2nd day, but dies on 3rd day, what would happen to your camera? would it still be salvageable if you later went to the same map, or would it disappear?

After several weeks, I met this situation, only to find out that camera will disappear - Sought everywhere of the map, especially point of death location, but no luck.
Understandable though. If you could upload videos 4 times in 3 days then the game will be much easier than normal.
